# Chevalley restriction theorem

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, characters

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}$I'm having a hard time understanding the proof of Chevalley's restriction theorem given by Humphreys in "[Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-6398-2), Springer–Verlag New York Inc. 1972". More specifically given $\lambda \in \Lambda^+$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\phi$ an irreducible representation of highest weight $\lambda$ and $f$ the function $x \mapsto \Tr(\phi (x)^k)$ the author states that
$f\mathclose\restriction_{\mathfrak{h}} = \Sym \lambda ^k + \sum m_{ \lambda }( \mu ) \Sym \mu ^k$
summed over $\mu \precneqq \lambda$, $\mu \in \Lambda^+$ where $\Sym \delta$ is the sum of all distinct $\mathcal{W}$-conjugates of $\delta$. I do not get why is true that the trace of the $k$-th power of the representation restricted to  $\mathfrak{h}$ is equal to the sum of the $k$-th power of the sum of all $\mathcal{W}$-conjugated weights of all the dominant $\mu \in \Pi(\lambda)$.

Comment: I think the argument is using three facts: (1) The $W$-invariant $k$-th power polynomials in ${\mathfrak h}$ are images of $k$-th power polynomials en ${\mathfrak h}$ under the averaging operator. (2) $\Lambda_+$ is Zariski dense in ${\mathfrak h}^*$ and thus the $k$-th powers $\lambda^k$ with $\lambda\in\Lambda_+$ generate the $k$-th power functions in ${\mathfrak h}$ (i.e., $\text{Sym}^k{\mathfrak h}^*$). (3) The set of weights of $V(\lambda)$ (where $V$ is the representation) is the union of the $W$-orbits of $\mu\in\Lambda_+$ such that $\mu\leq \lambda$ with corresponding multiplicities

Comment: constant in each orbit $W\mu$ (see 21.2 in Humphreys).

Comment: @FZaldivar Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}\DeclareMathOperator\trace{trace}$I can write the details of Humphreys' argument: For each integer $k\geq 1$ it suffices to show that the map $\theta:\Sym^k({\mathfrak g}^*)^N\rightarrow \Sym^k({\mathfrak h}^*)^W$ is surjective. Since the elements $\Sym\lambda^k$, for $\lambda\in\Lambda_+$ generate $\Sym^k({\mathfrak h}^*)^W$ it is enough to show that they are in the image of $\theta$. Now, for $\lambda\in\Lambda_+$ let $(\phi, V)$ be an (irreducible) representation of ${\mathfrak g}$ of highest weight $\lambda\in\Lambda_+$. Let $V=\bigoplus_{\mu\preceq\lambda}V_{\mu}$ be the decomposition in weight spaces and recall that each $\dim V_{\mu}=c(\mu)<\infty$ and $\dim_KV_{\lambda}=1$. Using this direct sum decomposition, the restriction (using $\theta$) to ${\mathfrak h}$ of the function $f=\trace(\phi^k)$ can be written for $h\in{\mathfrak h}$ as
$$f(h)=\trace(\phi^k)(h)=\sum_{\mu\preceq\lambda}\trace(\phi^k)(h)\big|_{V_{\mu}}=\sum_{\mu\preceq\lambda}c(\mu,k)\mu(h)^k$$
since in each restriction $(\phi^k)(h)$ is multiplication by $\mu(h)^k$ (the $V_{\mu}$ are weight spaces) and where $c(\mu,k)=\dim_KV_{\mu}$. Separating the $\mu\preceq\lambda$ in the orbits $W\mu$ under the action of $W$, the displayed formula becomes
\begin{align*}
f(h)&=\trace(\phi^k)(h)=\sum_{\mu\preceq\lambda}c(\mu,k)\sum_{w\mu\in W\mu} (w\mu)^k(h)\\
&=\sum_{\mu\preceq\lambda}c(\mu,k)\Sym(\mu^k)(h)\\
&=\Sym(\lambda^k)(h)+
\sum_{\mu\prec\lambda}c(\mu,k)\Sym(\mu^k)(h)
\end{align*}
where we used that $\dim V_{\lambda}=1$ and that the dimensions $\dim V_{w\mu}$ are constant in each orbit.